# Date_histogram and top_hits from unique values only

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do a date_histogram aggregation to show a sum of Duration for each hour.

I have the following documents:

```
{
  "EntryTimestamp": 1567029600000,
  "Username": "johndoe",
  "UpdateTimestamp": 1567029600000,
  "Duration": 10,
  "EntryID": "ASDF1234"
}
```

The following works very well but my problem is that sometimes multiple documents appear with the same EntryID. So ideally I would need to add a top_hits somehow, and order by the UpdateTimestamp as I need the last updated document for each unique EntryID. But not sure how to add this to my query.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                    "range": {
                        "EntryTimestamp": {
                            "gte": "1567029600000",
                            "lte": "1567065599999",
                            "format": "epoch_millis"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "query_string": {
                        "analyze_wildcard": true,
                        "query": "Username.keyword=johndoe"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "2": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "interval": "1h",
                "field": "EntryTimestamp",
                "min_doc_count": 0,
                "extended_bounds": {
                    "min": "1567029600000",
                    "max": "1567065599999"
                },
                "format": "epoch_millis"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "1": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "Duration"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a top_hits aggregation inside a terms aggregation.

The terms aggregation will get the distinct EntryIDs and the top hit aggregation inside of it will get only the most recent document (based on UpdateTimestamp) for each bucket (each distinct value) of the terms aggregation.

I have no clear syntax adapted to your context, and i believe you might run into some issues regarding the number of sub aggregations (i ran into some limitations with advanced aggregations in the past)

You can see [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/get-latest-value-for-each-unique-value/123196/2) post for more info on that; i hope it'll prove to be helpful to you.